# How to send the data from Kafka to ElasticSearch using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

i am using Python Language. I have csv file, I  need to convert into json and send to kafka and then to ElasticSearch.

I am able to convert Csv to Json and send to kafka consumer.  How to get the data from Kafka Consumer to ElasticSearch

Comment: maybe this helps: https://sematext.com/blog/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-how-to/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write any Python. Kafka itself provides a streaming integration API, called Kafka Connect. To use it, you just configure it with JSON files.

- Ingest CSV file into Kafka with https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir

  - Example of it in use: https://www.confluent.io/blog/ksql-in-action-enriching-csv-events-with-data-from-rdbms-into-AWS/
- Stream data from Kafka topic to Elasticsearch https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/

  - Example of it in use: https://www.confluent.io/blog/blogthe-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent, and wrote the above articles.*

Comment: How to download kafka-connect-elasticsearch  without business email id. I m working in one company but can't give since i am learning for my own not for company.

Comment: You don't need to provide an email id, or if you do, you can just use a throwaway one if you want (e.g. https://www.mailinator.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Logstash with Kafka input plugin to send data to Elasticsearch. It's easy to configure and run.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html